# Python Boto3 Module fetching API Keys with position parameter raising an exception

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I tried to fetch list of API Keys created in my aws account.  There are 50 Api keys.  I want to list 10 Api Keys per request. Here is the code snippet.

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('apigateway')
response = client.get_api_keys(
    limit=10,
    position="1",
)
print response
```

When I run the script, It is showing an error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    position="1",
  File "C:\Users\Murthy\workspace\my_project\venv\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 310, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Murthy\workspace\my_project\venv\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 599, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.errorfactory.BadRequestException: An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the GetApiKeys operation: Invalid position parameter
```

Am I doing wrong ?

Also maximum results per query is 500. How do we know total number of results to perform the pagination ?

Comment: If I don't specify position parameter, I am getting first 10 keys.

Comment: you have mention position="1" in the Q but in the error code you have mentioned position="10" ?

Comment: it would be great if you can add your entire snippet

Comment: Whatever the position, It is raising an exception.  Here is the entire snippet.  import boto3

client = boto3.client('apigateway')
response = client.get_api_keys(
    limit=10,
    position="1",
)
print response

Comment: Did you try `position=None` or `position=''` ?

Comment: None value is not accepting. position='' is accepting but raising the same exception. If I removed position parameter, it works well and showing the limited number of results. But for my requirement position argument is needed for pagination.

Comment: @Murthy , can you replace position to 'Position' and see if it works? boto3 doc for other services have parameter names starting with uppercase character .I am not sure , if it works or not , though your snippet looks good.

Comment: Tried the position with title case. The following error has been raised. 

botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in input: "Position", must be one of: position, limit, nameQuery, customerId, includeValues

Answer (score -2):

The position variable acts as a token. It is to be used to get the next page of your request.
In the first call to retrieve the usage plans, the position should be set to null, then to get the next page, you have to assign the position the value of the position in the previous response. The position variable is more like a token.

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('apigateway')
response = client.get_api_keys(
  limit=10,
  position=null,
)
print response
```

Your response would be something like this

```
{
"position": "vWQ3Uzc4bAY2YQ%3D%3D",
"items": [
    {
        "id": "fqewi1",
        "name": "3rd Party",
        "description": null,
        "apiStages": [],
        "throttle": {
            "burstLimit": 2,
            "rateLimit": 1.0
        },
.
.
.
}
```

Your next request would be in this format

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('apigateway')
response = client.get_api_keys(
  limit=10,
  position="vWQ3Uzc4bAY2YQ%3D%3D",
)
print response
```

This would return the next page. For the last page, the position would be null.

Comment: null is not an available keyword / datatype in python